# Why is clock synchronisation such a big deal in physics?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, time

I was reading Classical Mechanics : [The theoretical minimum by Leonard Susskind](https://theoreticalminimum.com/), and he says

> Assume that two clocks at different places can be synchronised.

I don't understand why one should do that. Can't one clock at the origin be enough?
Whenever I try to start on special relativity, this crops up.
Can someone explain this to me or at least point me towards any resources which explain such issues in detail? Especially special relativity related.

Comment: If you read the sentences/sections immediately after a second clock is introduced, it should be immediately clear why it was introduced.

Comment: @KyleKanos Do you mean in general in any book?

Comment: Correct. Any book that covers relativity should make it clear why there are 2 clocks if you read a little further.

Comment: @KyleKanos I will keep my eyes open, it has been some time since my last go at it. I keep going at it, but somewhere along the line lose motivation, no book seems good enough. Any recommendations?

Comment: @NeeladriReddy recommendation: stay motivated.

Comment: Can the question whether two clocks run at the same rate make any sense without synchronizing them first?

Comment: If you think carefully, any mental picture using only one clock is implicitly assuming a relationship between "time at point A" and "time at point B."  You cannot compare spatially separated events without defining a clock synchronization strategy.  See "Clock Postulate"

Comment: Special relativity notably challenges the notion of simultaneity. The [ladder-barn paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox) worked the best for our freshmen course to illustrate why you can't have Lorentz-transformed spacetime with absolute simultaneity. This is perhaps the shortest answer to the question "Can't one clock at the origin be enough?" - ladder (or pole, in some settings) would both be broken in parts by closing doors and stay intact. Being a macro-object, it can't be both at the same time.

Comment: "Can't one clock at the origin be enough?" - the books follow a quasi-historical path; they present some arguments and then arrive to a conclusion. But maybe it'll be helpful to you if you flipped it around. You're still thinking about space separately, with time flowing within it. Stop that. Think about *spacetime*. If (2D) space is a piece of paper, spacetime is a thick stack of papers. Except fused together into a block, and you can slice it at different angles - two observers will have different directions of time. Clocks are just a stand-in for the time coordinate at each point.

Comment: "Clock synchronization" simply means that the origin of all space-time coordinate frames must be fixed. When we talk about ordinary rotations (in 2D or 3D), the origin must be a fixed point. When we talk about SR transformations – Lorentz transformations – the origin must be fixed as well. This implies fixing the "zero position" as well as "zero time". After all, "Lorentz transformations" are just a hyperbolic version of ordinary rotations!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

All of special relativity is based on the assumption that any observer can set up a coordinate system and then label spacetime events with their coordinates in that system. Then we can use the Lorentz transformations to transform between the coordinate systems of different observers.

The positions of events are easy because I have an infinite number of rulers and simply by laying them one after the other I can create a grid that fills all of spacetime. Then when some event happens my colleague who happened to be standing where the event happened can just look at my rulers and note down the position.

But the time is trickier. Time measurements are easy for events at my position because I just look at my clock and note the time. But for any distant event I have to ask my colleague next to the event to note the time on their clock. I could wait for the light from the event to reach me, and subtract off the travel time to get the original time of the event, but this is now an indirect measurement of the time. This workable in SR, but in GR light travel times are impossible to calculate unless I know the exact trajectory the light took, and indeed the light could reach me by multiple paths as happens in gravitational lensing.

So the only safe option is to put a clock at each point of my grid of rulers then synchronise them all. That way the event coordinates can be recorded by a colleague standing at that point. But this only works if all the clocks can be synchronised, and this is harder that it appears at first sight. If I move my clock to yours so we can synchronise them my clock will be time dilated by the motion and this spoils the timing. That's why we resort to protocols like [Einstein synchronisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation).

Now this is all conceptual rather than realistic and we clearly don't actually measure events this way. However it is a concept that is at the heart of special relativity, and that's why books on SR tend to labour the point.

Comment: Thank you. But a new doubt - how do we know space/time is uniform in a given reference frame? I see it mentioned as a requirement, but how can it be verified experimentally and what does it really mean? I am asking because I have a vague sense that synchronizing clocks isn't enough, what if they don't run at the same rate due to them being at different places or something? I myself am not clear what I am asking, if you didn't get an inkling of the meaning of my question, it's because I myself am not clear what the issue is.

Comment: @NeeladriReddy Special relativity is the theory of flat spacetime so the spacetime is uniform by definition. If we move to GR then the meaning of a coordinate system becomes more complicated. In general we can't synchronise clocks in GR, and even if we did they wouldn't stay synchronised.

Comment: "The positions of events are easy": No.  Distances also change depending on the observer.  The same point in space and time translates to a different position and different time depending on the speed of the observer.  Also, what is "here" in the future depends on the speed of the observer.

Comment: @FlorianF all measurements are being made in my inertial frame.

Comment: @FlorianF, Moving a ruler does not _permanently_ change its length. I _perceive_ it to have a different length while it is in motion, but once I have finished laying down my grid of rulers, I can trust that they all have the same length (even the ones that I placed in the far distance) so long as none of them is moving with respect to me. Clocks are slightly different. Moving a clock does not _permanently_ change the rate at which it ticks, but the temporary slowdown that i perceive while moving it out to a distant location _does_ permanently change its "offset" from my time origin.

Comment: As the OP said, in SR you can work out the local time, assuming you have chosen an inertial reference frame.  You just look at a central watch and subtract the time for the light to reach you.  In GR both time and distance become tricky.

Answer (score 4):

Two clocks are required to show that the time and place where an event occurs is *relative* to the two observers (one moving and one stationary), even if the two clocks were synchronized in the first place. This is usually expressed using the [*Lorentz transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation),
\begin{align}
t' &= \gamma\left(t-vx/c^2\right) \\
x' &= \gamma(x-vt)
\end{align}
where $(x,\,t)$ are the coordinates in the stationary frame, $(x',\,t')$ the coordinates in the moving frame (moving with velocity $v$) and $\gamma^2=1/(1-v^2/c^2)$.

For an arbitrary time $t>0$, we find that $(x,\,t)$ and $(x',\,t')$ have different values, indicating that each of the two observers sees the same event happening at a different time and place as the other observer. Hence, two clocks would be required to analyze the scenarios, rather than a single one.

Answer (score -1):

When we want to compare clocks, there must be a method to compare them. Since time is not absolute in relativity theory, different observers will disagree on what events they consider simultaneous. So comparing clocks is no longer unambiguous.

To be able to compare clocks, therefore, we must have a method that yields the same outcome for all observers, regardless of these observers’ own motions. This is clock synchronization.